# How to check if a 3D line segment intersects a cylinder?

Tags: geometry, 3d

I have developed a check for a 2D case of a circle intersecting a 2D line segment, however there is a particular case that I can't figure out how to extend to 3D:

If one endpoint on the 3D line segment is inside the 2D projected circle, but above the cylinder, and the other endpoint is outside of the circle, but below the cylinder, how do I check if the line segment crossed the cylinder?

[image]

Comment: Do you care whether or not the line intersects the side of the cylinder, or is it all right if it just intersects the top and bottom without hitting the side?

Comment: It should be impossible for the line to intersect the ground of the cylinder because I am using this in a 'real life' situation. It is a simplified model of a robot arm link hitting a cylindrical obstacle, so there are separate collision rules for the line hitting the ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that each horizontal cross-section of the cylinder (a circle) has a radius of $r$. That means that on any slice of the cylinder, we have a circle of the form

$$x_c^2+y_c^2=r^2 \text{(Eqn.1)}$$

Now let's write the equation of the line as if we were looking at the whole thing from above (i.e. ignoring it in the z-direction and writing $y_l$ as a function of $x_l$). It would have an apparent equation of the form
$$y_l=mx_l+b \text{(Eqn 2)}$$
Now, if the line crosses the circle at at least one point, then $y_c=y_l$ and $x_c=x_l$. We substitute $y_l$ into $\text {Eqn 1}$ and $x_l$ into $\text {Eqn 1}$, making it

$$x_l^2+(mx_l+b)^2=r^2 \text{(Eqn.3)}$$
Now we can solve for $x_l$. We can plug that into $\text {Eqn 2}$ to find $y_l$, and because we know $y_c=y_l$ and $x_c=x_l$, we can solve for the other variables. If we know the location of $A$ and $B$, we can then find the position of that point in 3-dimensional space.

Comment: If I were to sum up this strategy, my goal is to find where the line segment crosses the circle, and then figure out which z-height it crossed at?

Comment: @AAC Yep. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Minimize the distance between them and then check to make sure the point is both on the line segment and the cylinder.

Comment: Sorry, what is "them" referring to? What am I minimizing?